# Как сделать динамическую таблицу в java android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Хочу сделать такой интерфейс: пользователь в текстовом поле вводит количество элементов в матрице. И на экране пользователя появляется матрица этого размера. При нажатии на элемент матрицы, чтобы срабатывало какое - то событие.

Подскажите как это лучше сделать на андроиде Java? С помощью каких view?

Answer (score -1):

Для отображения таблици лучше использовать GridView - Почитайте. Гдето здесь

> [Ваш путь к Андроид]/Android/docs/reference/android/widget/GridView.html

Вот примерно такой класс можно создать

public class Activity extends android.app.Activity implements OnKeyListener {

```
/**
 * Текстовое поле для ввода количества елементов матрицы
 */
private EditText et;

/**
 * Матрица, которая вам нужна. Просто создайте нужный вам класс
 */
private MyMetrix mat;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    LinearLayout ll=new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    ScrollView sv=new ScrollView(this);

    sv.addView(ll);

    et=new EditText(this);
    //регистрируем слушаетля ввода с клавиатуры
    et.setOnKeyListener(this);

    ll.addView(et);

    //создайте ваш обьект матрицы
    mat=new MyMetrix(this);
    mat.setVisible(false);

    //добавлени евашего обьекта в отображение
    ll.addView(mat);

    this.setContentView(sv);

}

@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int d, KeyEvent k) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try{

        if(v==et){
            //в текстовое поле что-то ввели

            String strInEditText=et.getText().toString();

            int numMatrix=Integer.parseInt(strInEditText);

            //изменяем количество елементов матрцы
            mat.setElementsCount(numMatrix);
            //устанавливаем, что бы видно было матрицу
            mat.setVisible(true);

        }

    }catch(Exception e){

    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * Ваш класс матрыцы. Просто отредактируйте его
 * @author 1
 *
 */
class MyMetrix extends GridView {

    private int count;

    public MyMetrix(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void setVisible(boolean visible){

    }

    public void setElementsCount(int newCount){
        count=newCount;
    }
}
```

}